# move file within FTP server using shell script

Tags: shell, ftp

i run into a following scenario

1. download the file from FTP server to local and process it

Ex: **FTPSERVER/dir/file_name  => /data/process/file_name**

1. After processing, move the file in FTP server to its archive folder

**Ex: FTPSERVER/dir/file_name  => FTPSERVER/dir/archive/file_name**

I have to do this using ***shell*** script. I have completed the first part using

***ncftpget -u $USER -p $PASS $HOST/DIR/$FILENAME***

I dont know how to do the second part.. which is moving the file into archive DIR of FTP server...

could someone help me on this...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

```
ftp -n $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASS
rename DIR/$FILENAME DIR/ARCHIVE/$FILENAME
EOF
```